# New questions page - caches for too long?

Tags: bug, status-completed, caching, newest-questions

The [newest questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest) seems to be caching for much longer than it used to (multiple minutes - sometimes more than 10 minutes).

I have seen this happen when the site updates, but it has been like that for a while now.

Was the cache expiration changed to expire less often? Is there an infrastructure issue here?

BTW - I am using 50 results per page.

Please reduce it to the more friendly 1 minute/30 seconds (or so) that it was.

---

Update: A guess here, but it looks like it caches a page until a *pagefull* of newer results come in.

Comment: Pretty sure it's supposed to be 30 seconds.

Comment: @asawyer - Yeah. But I am seeing it going to up to 12 minutes at a time.

Comment: I am seeing it too, since last night.

Comment: I just noticed this too; as of right now, the "Newest" question is 18 mins old, with 15 questions per page.  I'm pretty sure a new question has been asked in the last 18 minutes.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - If you look at the home page, you will see that indeed there are such questions...

Comment: Seems to be the worst on per site Metas

Comment: @BenBrocka - They already had a much longer cache expiry, guess whatever bug this is just exacerbated it.

Comment: The "newest" has been sitting idle for 20 minutes! I feel for the poor guy who posted a bad question that's stuck at the top of the queue, collecting negative votes at an increasing speed.

Comment: As a side note, it would be nice if admins either acknowledged the problem in the comments, or said that they cannot reproduce it. I hope this is not the new behavior, though :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight they've replied, the comment will appear whenever the cache expires

Comment: @BenBrocka LOL LOL LOL LOL LOL

Comment: Same to me, the newest question on the list is from 35 minutes ago :-s

Comment: When I saw your tweet, I checked and the questions were out of date for me too. Some refreshes later and newer question appeared again.

Comment: :-). Just a point I'm noticing this as well and I'm in London as is Oded in the linked question, which implies something. Maybe SE is having trouble with their European facing arm. And sorry, you edited your question as I was VTCing...

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but in West Coast US.  About 50% of my page loads are roughly one hour out of date.

Comment: I'm voting to close Oded's question as a dupe of this one because this one has the red tag and dev answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Newest" questions sometimes appears to be stale](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147517/newest-questions-sometimes-appears-to-be-stale) (because that one has a red tag and dev answer)

Comment: @PopularDemand - Jon Skeet favouritism?

Comment: @PopularDemand - Fair enough... voting to close my original as a dupe ;)

Comment: Certainly not, @Oded! I am wounded that you would suggest such a thing! And Jon, of course, didn't offer to award me any unreasonably large bounties for turning the tide of close votes. Nor did he promise to prioritize my SO questions in the future.

Comment: @PopularDemand - I meant from the SO devs... but feel free to be offended ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We have disabled the remote tag engine which handles all of our requests for tag lists.  We will take a look at it!

---

We have tracked this down and pushed a fix - the developer responsible will be our default selection on our internal wheel of blame :)

Comment: You could always just blame Tim Stone.  Everyone else is doing it.