# "Newest" questions sometimes appears to be stale

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New questions page - caches for too long?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147488/new-questions-page-caches-for-too-long)

I normally use the "newest" questions tab... and I've seen some strange behaviour this afternoon.

One minute the screen will be full of really recent questions - and the next (even in the same tab) it's about 50 minutes out of date.

Having asked on Twitter, it seems *some* other users are seeing the same effect.

(Chrome on Linux, if that's relevant.)

EDIT: This *may* be a duplicate of ["New questions page - caches for too long?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147488/new-questions-page-caches-for-too-long) - but I'm not sure. 50+ minutes is a *really* long time, and I'm seeing it intermittently. It's as if one server is miles out of date, and another one isn't...