# "Newest" questions not appearing

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro

I have `Qt` tagged as one of my favorites. When I click on the `Qt` tag in the sidebar in order to view just the `Qt` questions, a page will load showing the newest questions (as determined by looking at question posting time) and then immediately reload to show older question. I can see the same load/reload behavior if I click on the "Newest" tab while viewing `Qt` questions. This *only* happens with `Qt` not my other favorites.

I see there are questions about this from a year or so ago (["Newest" questions sometimes appears to be stale](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147517/newest-questions-sometimes-appears-to-be-stale)  and [New questions page - caches for too long?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147488/new-questions-page-caches-for-too-long))

Is there some setting on my end which may be causing this?

**Update:** Is the "Career" ad block causing this? Everytime I click on the "newest" tab the page loads with later questions and no ad block. Less than a second later the page reloads with older questions and the ad block.

---

**The page as it first loads:** (or after clicking the "newest" tab) Note the time on the first question and the absence of the Career ad block

[image]

### ----------

**The page a half second layer:** The questions are older and completely different. Again note the question time and the appearance of the ad block.
[image]

Comment: Are you on [newest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt?sort=newest)? Give us a screenshot. If not, click on 'newest', then next time you click on a tag, it should go to 'newest'.

Comment: Do you happen to have Ignored Tags too? In such case, if you chose to hide questions with those tags it explain such behavior.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I am seeing this specifically on the `Qt` tag page, not my main SO page.